# Polymer returning JSON object on AJAX success not using jquery

Tags: ajax, json, polymer

I'm trying to animate SVG images based on the degree provided by user. The requirement is that I have to read the degree from an external JSON file. I'm new to polymer so how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [iron-ajax](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax).

Here's an example:

```
<iron-ajax url="post.json" auto last-response="{{theResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
```

The `url` attribute here refers to the url target of the request, `auto` means that it performs the request either when the `url` or `params` changes, and `last-response` refers to the last response object you received.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned. But when i try to access the object returned as response it shows undefined.